# Cannot see an EC2 VPN server from another EC2 instance

Tags: networking, openvpn, amazon-ec2, udp

I'm using openVPN to connect to one EC2 instance from another.  The client cannot see the server, however, despite that servers outside of AWS can see the server and successfully negotiate with it.

It fails with "Cannot resolve host address": [log output here](http://pastie.org/private/ffcakby58gm06plrjtxlyg).  [Config here](http://pastie.org/private/fa0oymktgt4vnaaymnjq)

I speculate that this is because UDP isn't configured properly.  I've already opened the ODP ports on that instance via the AWS SecurityGroups - this didn't work, both for all incoming UDP, and/or for UDP from the server IP.

Does anyone know what might be misconfigured in AWS to prevent this?

Comment: Can you post your config? This looks like more of a configuration issue as it tries to resole the ip address...

Comment: There is no IP to resolve - I'm giving it the exact IP address